# ByteArrayOutput/InputStream on transparent image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to send a `BufferedImage` over socket, I do this by converting the image to `byte[]` and then send it over after encoding it in Base64. I'm sending over 2 BufferedImages, one of them is "full", the other one is about 50% transparent. The problem I'm having, is that when they arrive, the second image is still visually transparent, but when I get the data array via Raster, it has been changed.

I made a small test code to demonstrate the problem;

```
        BufferedImage levelBufferedOriginal = ...
        BufferedImage backgroundBufferedOriginal = ...
        
        byte[] levelDataOriginal = ((DataBufferByte) levelBufferedOriginal.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        byte[] backgroundDataOriginal = ((DataBufferByte) backgroundBufferedOriginal.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] temp = null, temp2=null;
        try {
            ImageIO.write(levelBufferedOriginal, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            temp = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            
            baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(backgroundBufferedOriginal, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            temp2 = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        
        BufferedImage levelBufferedNew = null;
        BufferedImage backgroundBufferedNew = null;
        
        try {
            levelBufferedNew = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(temp));
            backgroundBufferedNew = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(temp2));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        byte[] levelDataNew = ((DataBufferByte) levelBufferedNew.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        byte[] backgroundDataNew = ((DataBufferByte) backgroundBufferedNew.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        
        
        System.out.println("LEVEL: " + Arrays.equals(levelDataOriginal, levelDataNew));
        System.out.println("BACKGROUND: " + Arrays.equals(backgroundDataOriginal, backgroundDataNew));
```

All I do here, is simply transform the `BufferedImage` to `byte[]`, then back, and compare the data I get from `DataBufferByte`. The output is

> LEVEL: false
>
> BACKGROUND: true

Background is the "full" image, and Level is the one with some transparent pixels.

If the general idea is wrong, I would like to hear another, all I want is to be able to exactly recreate 2 bufferedImages.

Comment: Are the images visually different? As you mention, the images are translucent. It could be that the PNG encoding/decoding roundtrip changes the values for some transparent pixels, without affecting the visuals of the image. See premultiplied alpha vs non-premultiplied.

Comment: The images visually are the same. Problem I get, is when I start editing the level image data (levelDataNew) to "-1" (to set a pixel transparent), it becomes black instead, so I don't see the background behind it. Whereas an edit to levelDataOriginal will set the pixel transparent.

Comment: What do you mean by "-1"? 0xFF? A completely transparent pixel is 0x0, while a completely opaque one should be 0xff. Also, the premultiplied state is important, if you are trying to "fade in" what you already have "faded out" (made transparent).

Comment: If you set a cell in `levelDataOriginal` to -1, it becomes transparent.


Im making a small Worms clone, I have 2 images, background and foreground, when something explodes, I just set the foreground to transparent; http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3658/40580303.png

The bottom right is the "client" and the top left is the "server", the images are sent over correctly, but compare the "ground" around the top left explosion, in the server, where the image is loaded from disk, I can "erase" the ground, but in the image that was sent over, the ground remains intact.

Comment: Hmmm.. I think I have a theory. Have a look at the color models of the images, are they the same? Is one, or both using IndexedColorModel? Could it be that the PNG w/r roundtrip re-arranges the colors, so that the transparent pixel is no longer at the same index?

Comment: System.out.println(levelBufferedOriginal.getType());
   System.out.println(levelBufferedNew.getType());

Both prints out "13", so I guess they use the same color model?

Comment: That means they use the same color model type (ie. IndexColorModel). Try printing the contents of the color map arrays, and you'll probably see that they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit: What we have established so far:**

- The images (both before and after) are TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED (13) with IndexColorModel (color map)
- The before image has a transparent color in the color map, at index 255 (which is the value -1 in the byte array, as Java uses signed `byte`s). The after image has a different value at this index, that is not transparent.
- The images are serialized/deserialized in PNG format, using ImageIO
- The images are visually equal, but the raw pixel data (the byte array) differs

Which leads to the conclusion that the ImageIO PNGImageWriter re-arranges the entries in the color map when writing, resulting in different pixel data/color map.

This basically leaves us with two options:

1. Serialize the image data in a different way, to assure the color map/pixel data is not modified. It is possible to send the pixel data array, along with the color map array and the height/width of the image, and then re-create the image exactly at the client. This is quite a bit of code, and is probably covered by other questions on SO.
2. Don't rely on the pixel data/color maps being the same. Use the value of `((IndexColorModel) levelBufferedNew.getColorModel()).getTransparentPixel()` to test for/set transparency instead of the hardcoded value `-1`. This requires pretty much no other change in your code.

Note: These solutions will only work for TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED (13) images.

For a more generic (but possibly slower) approach, use the code in the original answer to set transparent parts, and use `(levelBufferedNew.getRGB(x, y) >> 24) == 0` to test for transparency. This should work even  for TYPE_INT_ARGB or TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR.

**original answer:**

Instead of fiddling with the image at byte array level, why not try using normal Java2D? ;-)

Something like:

```
Graphics2D g = levelBufferedNew.createGraphics();
try {
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
    g.fillOval(x, y, w, h); // The area you want to make transparent
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

...should work.

PS: As the images use `IndexColorModel`, you can use the `getTransparentPixel()` to get the transparent pixel index, instead of relying on it being at a certain index (-1/255). Then you can still manipulate at byte array level. ;-)

Comment: Another reason for using byte array is so that I can figure out where the ground is; I can ask if pixel (x, y) is != -1, then its solid ground, so that object has to collide with it, and this is heart of the problem, despite the images looks identical, the byte array data is messed up. Cells that are -1 in the original aren't -1 in the transmitted version.

Comment: You are assuming -1 (or really 255) means transparent. It doesn't. Any value may be transparent. You must query the IndexColorModel.

Comment: Well, I edited an image in Paint.NET, and the transparent parts of the image had value -1. If it has like != -1, I see color, as soon as I change it to -1, its gone.

Comment: The byte value -1 really means index 255 into the color map. Different software (like ImageIO) could store the transparent value in a different index in the color map. This is probably what's happening. That's why the image is visually equal, but bytes differ.

Comment: So I just changed my code to get rid of the byte array entirely - it works! Thanks